# rails - authentication, authorization and auditing confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aaa-security-protocol

I am trying to decide on an AAA plugin/s but there seems to be so many of them! and a lot of the posts seem quite old, 07/08.

I saw goldberg but it seems like the site is down...

my app needs login,logout and forgotten passwords and needs to be able to restrict a user based on controllers/methods(role based).

On the auditing side I need to be able to log when a user edits/creates data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can start looking at [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication, and [CanCan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for *simple* authorization.

for logging, don't know if there are any plugins, but you easily can write some observer.